# pivot/unpivot tables mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

can you make pivot/unpivot in mysql similar to ms sql server?

thanks

Here's a link to how SQL Pivot works: [link text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Comment: If you look at the combination of `[mysql]` and `[pivot]` tags, you'll see numerous examples.  PIVOT/UNPIVOT isn't supported on MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for PIVOT. Instead you can use a JOIN. For example:

```
SELECT Table1.Value AS AValue, Table2.Value AS BValue
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.grp = Table2.grp AND Table2.Type = 'B'
WHERE Table1.Type = 'A'
```