# MySQL query to convert a table into distinct column and other column count array?

Tags: mysql

My data table is as below:

```
ID WEEK   RESULT 
1   13     GOOD
2   13     BAD
3   13     GOOD
4   13     WORST
5   14     GOOD
6   14     BAD
7   14     WORST
8   15     BAD
9   15     WORST
```

I need a sql query to create an array as below:

```
WWEK   GOOD_RESULT   BAD_RESULT   WORST_RESULT   TOTAL
13            2             1       1              4
14            1             1       1              3
15            0             1       1              2
```

Can anyone please help me to find an appropriate mysql query?

Comment: What do you mean by array?  This question is very similar to your previous one -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365894/mysql-query-to-select-a-distinct-column-and-the-count-of-a-value-in-another-colu If you need more columns, then you will add additional case/aggregates.  Do you need this data returned to your application?  Please clarify what you need.

Comment: These links may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480803/pivot-unpivot-tables-mysql  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  WEEK,
  SUM(RESULT='GOOD') As GOOD_RESULT,
  SUM(RESULT='BAD') As BAD_RESULT,
  SUM(RESULT='WORST') AS WORST_RESULT,
  COUNT(*) As TOTAL
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY
  WEEK
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5e80/2).